# SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated in Netty with self signed certificates on separates machines

Tags: java, ssl, netty

The Setup:

- I have as setup using a Netty (v4.0.8) client/server using an SSLHandler to secure the connection.
- On the Server I’m running the Netty Part within a Jetty Environment, the client is a JAR I'm calling from the command line.
- I have self-signed certificates for the clients and the server.
- I have the CA-Certificate in a trust-Store that I Use on both sides (server and client). I do have also the CA-Certificate in the JRE KeyStore (just in case)
- I have my own trust-store implementation to trace down the issue I have.

The Problem:

- If Client and Server are running on the same machine, every thing is fine.
- If Client and Server are running on different machines, I do get a SSLPeerUnverifiedException on the Server first (and then on the client).
- I also do have a python implementation of the client (using the SSL Connection). This own works fine, on the same as well as on separate machines.

The Analysis so far shows

- The Trust-Manager correctly calls the getAcceptedIssuers() on Client and Server
- The checkServerTrusted() is called on the Client
- The checkClientTrusted() is NOT called on the Server

Instead I do get the exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificateChain(SSLSessionImpl.java:401)
```

As this takes some time on the server, on the client side a Time-Out occurs

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
```

and subsequently a

```
SSLPeerUnverifiedException:  javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

occurs.

The Exception occurs in netty's userEventTriggered() method of the Handler-Class. I do check, if the incoming event is an SslHandshakeCompletionEvent and when I try to get the Certificate from the SSLSession.

Answer (score 0):

The basis problem was a timeout. I tracked down the issue by having a closer look at the SslHandshakeCompletionEvent, which provides "isSuccess()" and "cause()". The Cause pointed me to the imeout exception.

I fixed the issue by increasing the timeout of the SSLHandler in the netty Initialiser-Classes.